# How to Compare Two Array of Objects to Determine Create, Update, Delete in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, compare

I've been tasked with creating an API connector between two systems. I needed to compare employees objects in SystemA and SystemB, then determine which employees would be new users, updating users, and users to be deleted in SystemB.

The goal is as follows:

1. Take an array of objects from SystemA and take an array of objects from SystemB. Then compare the two array of objects, and determine which objects need to be CREATED, UPDATED, and DELETED in SystemB.
2. If there are objects in SystemA's array that are not in SystemB's array, then those objects should be CREATED in SystemB system.
3. If there are objects in SystemA's array that are also in SystemB's array, then those objects in SystemB should be UPDATED.
4. If there are objects in SystemB's array that are not in SystemA's array, then those objects should be DELETED from SystemB's system.

Comment: You need to provide a *lot* more detail in this question. Please read [ask]. Even if you are self-answering, the question has to have enough detail so that others can answer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with.

```js
// SystemA
const objArray1 = [
  { id: "1", name: "John" },
  { id: "2", name: "Jack" },
  { id: "3", name: "Sam" },
  { id: "4", name: "Bill" },
];

// SystemB
const objArray2 = [
  { id: "1", name: "John" },
  { id: "3", name: "Sam" },
  { id: "5", name: "Bob" },
];

const array1IDs = objArray1.map((item) => {
  return item.id
})
// Result: array1IDs = ["1", "2", "3", "4"];

const array2IDs = objArray2.map((item) => {
  return item.id
})
// Result: array2IDs = ["1", "3", "5"];

// FIND SYNCED USERS
// Compare the id value of each item in objArray1 with each item of objArray2
// Return the ones that match. 
const syncedUsers = objArray1.filter((item) => {
  const found = objArray2.find((element) => element.id === item.id);
  return found;
});

// FIND NEW USERS
// Filter through each item in objArray1.
// If array2IDs array doesn't include a value matching the id of the current item,
// then return the current item
const newUsers = objArray1.filter((item) => {
  if (!array2IDs.includes(item.id)) {
    return item;
  }
});

// FIND USERS TO DELETE
// Filter through each item in objArray2.
// If array1IDs array doesn't include a value matching the id of the current item,
// then return the current item
const usersToDelete = objArray2.filter((item) => {
  if (!array1IDs.includes(item.id)) {
    return item;
  }
});

// Log results (or work with resulting arrays)
console.log("Synced Users:", syncedUsers);
console.log("New Users:", newUsers);
console.log("Users to delete:", usersToDelete);
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.